# Spring Boot Redis prevents termination of non-interactive application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis

I'm writing a batch application with the Spring Boot Redis starter, and everything works fine except that the batch application doesn't terminate after all my `ApplicationRunner` are done.

I see that there are plenty of threads from Lettuce still running, I guess this is WAI for web applications, but it's not suitable for any non-interactive application.

This is an example to reproduce my behavior:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RedisSandbox implements ApplicationRunner {
    private final RedisTemplate redisTemplate;
    
    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        // any operation with redisTemplate
    }
}
```

It is noteworthy that if I configure the same `ApplicationRunner` with the `RedisTemplate` but without performing any operation with it, then the application terminates at the end of my `ApplicationRunner` as usual.
I reckon this might be some pooled resource under the hood of Lettuce which is never reclaimed.

How could I get a clean termination (I don't want to call `SpringApplication.exit()` or `System.exit()` because that would break the tests)?
Maybe there is a way to give Lettuce a hint when I'm done using Redis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the hint for Lettuce that I'm done using Redis is invoking the method `ClientResources.shutdown()` which can be autowired.

It still dirties the application context beyond repair, so this is not an optimal solution for testing.